# What library is wglSwapIntervalEXT in?

Tags: windows, opengl

I know I need to call wglGetProcAddress to get the address of the extension wglSwapIntervalEXT. Assuming the call to wglGetProcAddress succeeds, is wglSwapIntervalEXT located in opengl32.lib?

Comment: How are you referencing it? See http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/177744-wglSwapIntervalEXT

Comment: Try using glew to avoid the need to manually load the extension functions you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> wglSwapIntervalEXT located in opengl32.lib?

No.

opengl32.dll is basically a trampoline into the actual OpenGL implementation provided by the GPU driver, the so called ICD (Independent Cient Driver). It also contains a software rasterizer, but that's just a fallback.

opengl32.lib is just sort of a table of contents for the DLL.

Comment: So making a call to wglSwapIntervalEXT calls directly into the GPU driver rather than going through opengl32.dll which the standard opengl functions do?

Comment: @user782220: Also the standard OpenGL functions go directly into the GPU driver. The opengl32.dll is merely a trampoline into the GPU driver and if there's a ICD available all OpenGL function calls go directly into that one.